# O valor verdadeiro de algum número se modifica quando eu mudo o tipo de float dele.?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, float, ieee-754

Alterar o meu conjunto de dados para **float32** ou **float16**, está alterando o valor "verdadeiro" dos meus dados?

Se eu tenho o valor *3.6*, usando o python e lendo em **float64** ele permanece *3.6*, mas ele muda quando coloco em **float32**, vira *3.5999999046325684*, baseado na IEEE 754. Fazer essa conversão direta está alterando o meu verdadeiro valor para aquele dado?

Comment: Sim, esses tipos não possuem exatidão, então cada um vai representar de um jeito, será próximo, mas não exato.

Comment: @Maniero se tratando de machine learning, alterar uma base de dados para float16 por exemplo, estaria modificando a minha base original?, eu fiz isso, e consegui por acaso uma acurácia melhor e um menor consumo de energia.

Comment: Isso pode fazer sentido, não entendo muito da área específica, mas faz sentido. Em geral usando ML não precisa tanto da exatidão, mas conseguir eficiência pode ser uma boa, embora claro, se quer eficiência extrema, não use Python.